# Inequality relating arccos and scalar product.

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Does anybody know of a quick, clean, algebraic way to see that for any unit vectors $a,b,c$ in $R^3$ we have the inequality
$arccos(a\cdot c)\leqslant arccos(a\cdot b)+arccos(b\cdot c)$?
I have tried to look up relevant trig identities, but didn't find a good one.

Comment: It looks like this is the triangle inequality for angles in 3D to me.

Comment: Isn't simply $\arccos(a\cdot b)$ the (planar) angle between $a$ and $b$? I guess you are taking $\arccos$ with range $[0,\pi)$...

Comment: Yeah its exactly this inequality. From which trig identies does it follow? @Hugo: Yes

Comment: It is the triangular inequality for the spherical geometry. $(a,b,c)$ are three points on the unit sphere. The quantities are the lengths of the (spherical) segments joining them (or geodesics, if you like).